# Is it possible to use custom allocation operator to create a STACK object?

Tags: c++

Ok, if I want to create a heap object with a custom new operator, I know that I need to overload the `new` operator like this:

```
void* operator new(size_t size, int unused)
{
    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    //some custom code
    return ptr;
}
```

And then, if I want to create a heap object using this overloaded operator I would do this:

```
SomeClass* a = new(0) SomeClass;
```

The question is: can I do something like this to create a stack object?

Comment: I definitely don't recommend it (besides, what's the difference between a normal stack variable and dynamically allocate of the stack? You still can't e.g. put the pointer in a collection or return it) but your system *may* have the [`alloca`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) function.

Comment: Oh and a warning about the `alloca` function, you can't actually use it in your operator, since it *must* be used in the function whose stack it should allocate from.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the problem is, I'm writing a simple memory manager which should take a note of every allocated object by means of overriding the new operator. The overriden new operator should add into a map<> some information about the block allocated, however, creating a pair<> to be inserted into the map<> actually calls this same new operator, and then again and again until stack overflow. While allocating another object on the heap seems to be impossible inside new. I'd like to create a pair<> for this map without using the overriden new operator, if you know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with other answers that you probably don't need this but you could do it. See sample code below, just allocate the memory ahead of time and pass it into placement new. You might want to do this if you are using the array new[] form where you might do something like

void *rawMemory = operator new[](25*sizeof(std::stack));

if you had an array of stacks that you had a factory method that managed the resources or something. Either way it depends on your application and use cases. Below shows a simple example

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <stack>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  void *rawMemory = operator new(sizeof(std::stack<unsigned int>));
  std::stack<unsigned int> *s = new (rawMemory) std::stack<unsigned int>;

  s->push(10);

  std::cout << s->top() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Second example using the array version, which seems more useful where you may be managing 25 different stacks and handing them to clients. Also, answering your comment. See that the container is defined in the stack definition this time, in this case I am using a vector for the container. Stack is a container but it has an underlying container that defaults to deque

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  typedef std::stack<unsigned int,std::vector<unsigned int> > StackType;

  void *rawMemory = operator new[](25*sizeof(StackType));

  StackType *stacks = static_cast<StackType*> (rawMemory);

  // allocate
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; ++i )
  {
    new (stacks+i) StackType;
  }

  stacks[1].push(10);
  std::cout << stacks[1].top() << std::endl;

  // don't forget to delete or smart resize
  for ( int i = 24; i >= 0; --i )
  {
    StackType x;
    std::swap ( x, stacks[i] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, isn't std::stack just a container? Does it actually have anything to do with the stack where stack objects are allocated?

Comment: see my comments above.  Stack is a container but it has an underlying container that defaults to deque

Answer (score 1):

You can define a macro like this:

```
#define STACK_NEW(T) new (alloca(sizeof(T))) T
```

that uses *placement new* and `alloca()` to allocate a block on the stack and construct an object of type `T` on top of it. You can also define an array version:

```
#define STACK_NEW_ARRAY(T, n) new (alloca(n * sizeof(T))) T
```

You'd use this macro in the following ways:

```
int * p = STACK_NEW(int);
MyObj * q = STACK_NEW(MyObj) (my, constructor, parameters);
int * r = STACK_NEW_ARRAY(int, 42);
```

You'll have destruct these objects manually:

```
q->~MyObj();
```

Deleting them will have undefined behavior.

***WARNING***: This whole facility is very unsafe. I'd strongly recommend against having such systematically dangerous tools in your codebase. As far as I can see, there is no safe way to use it and it *will* cause you pain!